# Collapsing m:n relation to two 1:n relations in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have class and students.

Student can enroll multiple class and class can have more students enrolled.

Now having 2 tables

```
           student                             class
pk_id |  name  |  lastname |                  pk_id | subject |
```

when i want to create m:n relation another table will be generated

```
student_class
pk_student_id | pk_class_id | ...
```

However, from modeling point of view, this are basicly two 1:n relations.

But i just cannt wrap my mind around one thing, what is "1" and what is "n" in this relation, is "1" `student` and `class` and "n" `student_class`? or is that vice versa? Both cases seems fine in my head.

Thanks for help, i appreciate all explanation.

Comment: Hint: Think student_class as "classroom" or "group".

Comment: that mean its still m:n... , student can be in multiple classrooms and clasroom as multiple students

Comment: `student` has a 1:n relationship with student_class.pk_student_id. `class` has a 1:n relationship with... you can finish this sentence

Comment: Right, what if you add a time to student_class? A student cannot be in two places at same time.

Comment: @Sai thats 1:1 ....